# Using the Mono Soft Debugger with Emacs

Tags: debugging, emacs, mono, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Does anyone have any experience with using Emacs and a debugger (like the Mono soft debugger) with mono (unity in particular) projects?

The debugger that comes with MonoDevelop is fine, but, as I am using Emacs as my primary editor, I'd like to use that for debugging mono/unity apps if possible.

Any tips or suggestions about how to best go about setting this up? Is there anything special I have to do for Unity projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look into using the command-line version of the debugger: https://github.com/mono/sdb

Comment: Thank you. Looks good so far. Integrates well with the Grand Unified Debugger.